# What is the best way to insert values into two separate tables in different JFrames?

Tags: java, jtable, tablemodel

I have question regarding parsing values to a different table.

I have a user interface containing a JTable. 
I also have an admin interface with another Jtable.

If a user added a row to the JTable in the User Interface JFrame, i need it to update or insert the same data into the admin table stored in a different JFrame.

What is the best approach for this?

Currently I have three classes:

**Main** - Contains all Methods for inserting table values:

```
public class Main1 {

public Object[][] userData;
    public Object[][] adminData;
    final public String[] userColumns =  {"Acc Number", "Firstname", "Lastname", "Cost ","Hours", "Time","Date","Approved"};
    final public String[] adminColumns = {"Acc Number", "Firstname", "Lastname", "Cost ","Hours", "Time","Date","Approved"};
    final DefaultTableModel userTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(userData, userColumns);
    final DefaultTableModel adminTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(adminData, adminColumns);
    final JTable userTable = new JTable(userTableModel);
    final JTable adminTable1 = new JTable(adminTableModel);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserGUI gui = new UserGUI();
        gui.GUI();     

    }

   public class ADD implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                    userTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1});
                    adminTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1});adminTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**User** - Calls the ADD method in the Main table, straightforward actionlistener. And the JTable is pulled using the following:

```
JPanel userTablePanel = new JPanel();
userTablePanel.setLayout(null);    
userTablePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Request History", TitledBorder.LEFT, TitledBorder.CENTER, new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.PLAIN, 14), Color.BLACK));
userTablePanel.setBounds(0, 320, frameWidth, 200);

int tablePadding = 10;
JScrollPane userTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
userTableScrollPane.setBounds(tablePadding, 20, frameWidth - (2 * tablePadding), 180 - tablePadding);
userTableScrollPane.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

userTable.setModel(userTableModel);
userTableScrollPane.setViewportView(userTable);
userTableScrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));

userTablePanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
userTable.setBackground(new Color(150,150,150));

userTable.setVisible(true);
userTableScrollPane.setVisible(true);
userTablePanel.add(userTableScrollPane);
```

**Admin** - Shows the Table and Headers but doesnt insert the data from the "ADD" method above...

```
adminTable.setModel(adminTableModel);
adminTableModel.addRow(new Object[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}); <--This works in its own class but doesnt work outside class....
userTableScrollPane.setViewportView(adminTable);
userTableScrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(new Color(230,230,230));
adminTable.setVisible(true);
userTableScrollPane.setVisible(true);
```

**Essentially, What im after is, How do i insert values from the Main "ADD" method into the Admin JTable? The Tablemodel Headers are pulled but not the data...**

Your help is much appreciated, let me know if this is completely wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I found the solution.

**I needed to parse the DefaultTableModel; which contained the data, as a parameter rather than the actual JTable, silly mistake.**

**Main Class - open AdminGUI method:**
Passed the userTableModel stored globally in Main Class.

```
public Object[][] userData;
final public String[] userColumns =  {"Acc Number", "Firstname", "Lastname", "Cost ","Hours", "Time","Date","Approved"};
final DefaultTableModel userTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(userData, userColumns);
final JTable userTable = new JTable(userTableModel);


public class ADMIN implements ActionListener {    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        AdminGUI a = new AdminGUI(userTableModel);
        a.getClass();
    }
}
```

**AdminGUI Class**
Admin Class required parsing the TabelModel into a new JTable which seemed to work fine.

```
public final class AdminGUI extends System1 {
   public AdminGUI(DefaultTableModel userTableModelClone) {
        JTable adminTable = new JTable(userTableModelClone);
        adminTable.setModel(userTableModelClone);

}
}
```

Thanks for your help. May help someone else in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Share the TableModel:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...);
JTable table1 = new JTable( model );
JTable table2 = new JTable( model );
```

When ever you make a change to table1 the change will be reflected in table2 (and vice versa) because both table share the same TableModel.

Also, don't use a null layout!!! Don't use setBounds()!!! Swing was designed to be used with layout managers, for too many reasons to list here.

Comment: Do i store this in the Main Class? or does Table2 need to be in the AdminGUI class as a global variable... It pulls the headers but the data is not "copied" over or inserted from one class to another...